# How to use a variable as a select statement and then sum multiple values in a variable?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have multiple rows with the following columns:

```
col1
col2
col3
col4
```

I want to say if rows where col3 equals col2 of other rows where col1 equals 'a111', then sum col4 of the rows where col3 equals col2 of other rows where col1 equals 'a111', and then rename the sum column to "Total".

Example table with the four columns and four rows:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
---- ---- ---- ----
     a222 a333 4444
a111 a333
     a555 a444 1111
a111 a444
```

I've tried the following but it does not work.

```
Declare
var1 = Select col2 from table1 where col1='a111';
var2 = Select col3 from table1 where col3=var1;
var3 = Select col4 from table1 where col3=var1;
Begin
If var2=var1
Then Select SUM(var3) As "Total";
End
```

Expected result is:

```
Total
5555
```

I do not have the strongest of knowledge in programming overall or Oracle. Please ask any questions and I will do my best to answer.

Comment: It would help us to help you if you could provide some sample data for your tables, along with the expected output you're wanting to get.

Comment: It sounds like you might just wants joins and conditional aggregation, but your description is rather abstract so it's hard to tell really.

Comment: Edited to add sample data and the expected output.

Comment: If you had an answer to your question, you should add it as an answer, rather than editing your question. That way, it's much clearer that the question has been answered.

Comment: I did not know at the time I could write an answer to my own question other than editing my question. Thank you for informing me, Boneist. Modus, I am a new user here. In a comment, please say what Boneist said if you are going to edit the answer from a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I believe I've determined the answer myself. I over complicated what I wanted. Thank you anyway.

Answer:

```
Select Sum(col4) as "Total" from table1 where col3 in (Select col2 from table1 where col1='a111')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is convoluted and hard to follow without an example of the data you have and an example of the data you want.. but translating your pseudocode into sql gives:

> Declare
>   var1 = Select col2 from table1 where col1='[table2.col2 value]';

Called "find" in my query

> var2 = Select col3 from table1 where col3=var1;
>   var3 = Select col4 from table1 where col3=var1;

Achieved by joining the table back to the "find"

> Begin
>   If var2=var1
>   Then Select SUM(var3) As "Total";
>   End

Achieved with a sum of var3 on only rows where var1=var2, in "ifpart"

```
SELECT SUM(var3) FROM
(
  SELECT alsot1.col3 as var2, alsot1.col4 as var3
  FROM
    table1 alsot1
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT t1.col2 as var1
      FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col2
     ) find
    ON find.var1 = alsot1.col3
  ) ifpart
WHERE
  var1 = var2
```

This could be simplified, but I present it like this because it matches your understanding of the problem. The query optimizer will rewrite it anyway when the time comes to run it so it only pays to start messing with how it's done if performance is poor

By the way, you clearly said that two tables join via a common named col2 but you then in your pseudocode said the tables join on col1=col2. I followed your pseudocode

Comment: I've edited my post a bit now to include more information and try to better translate what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that hierarchical queries could handle. E.g. something like:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT NULL col1, 'a222' col2, 'a333' col3, 4444 col4 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'a111' col1, 'a333' col2, NULL col3, NULL col4 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT NULL col1, 'a555' col2, 'a444' col3, 1111 col4 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'a111' col1, 'a444' col2, NULL col3, NULL col4 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'a666' col1, 'a888' col2, NULL col3, NULL col4 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT NULL col1, 'a777' col2, 'a888' col3, 7777 col4 FROM dual)
SELECT col1,
       SUM(col4) col4_total
FROM   (SELECT connect_by_root(col1) col1,
               col4
        FROM   your_table
        CONNECT BY col3 = PRIOR col2
        START WITH col1 IS NOT NULL) -- start with col1 = 'a111')
GROUP BY col1;

COL1 COL4_TOTAL
---- ----------
a666       7777
a111       5555
```